# How i can run web-application from GitHub on local server using Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, server

I downloaded [this web application](https://github.com/jirkapinkas/java-blog-aggregator) from GitHub, and I want make some changes and try it out for myself. My problem is I don't know how to run it on local server. Does anybody know how to run it on Jetty, Tomcat or another web server?

In the description on GitHub the author wrote:
*To run in development mode (using embedded HSQL database):
Run this application using embedded Jetty server: mvn -P dev jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"*

But I'm not sure what this is. Is it a config for the server? Where must I use this code to run the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install anything else.

Embedded HSQL and embedded Jetty means that both database and web container are deployed (and undeployed) automatically via the application's own code. `mvn` just tells Maven to run that Jetty using the `dev` profile, which will launch the web application within.

All I did was:

```
git clone git@github.com:jirkapinkas/java-blog-aggregator.git
cd java-blog-aggregator
mvn -P dev jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

and everything started up OK. That's really all.